# An estimate involving Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I encountered the following computation in a paper:

[image]

The highlighted $t$ is mysterious to me, how did it end up there? For some guidance: the first line is fundamental theorem of calculus and change of variables. The last equality is change of variables and fubini. Thanks!

Comment: An upper bound $(\int_0^tf(r)dr)^2\le t\int_0^t[f(r)]^2dr$, where in this case $f(r):=\nabla u(r\xi)\cdot\xi$, might make sense iif we know more about $u$.

Comment: I think this is the direction to head. Assuming this is so, can you discuss this inequality in the answer section?

Comment: Is "H" a Hermite polynomial or a Struve function?

Comment: @K.defaoite no, its just shorthand for a type of measure on the surface of the sphere. "n-1 dim Hausdorff measure" to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jensen’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) should do the trick. Replacing $dr$ with the probability measure $dr/t$ on the interval $[0,t]$ and using convexity of $x \mapsto x^2$ furnishes the inequality
$$ \left( \int_{[0, t]} f(r) \frac{dr}{t} \right)^2 \leq \int_{[0, t]} f(r)^2 \frac{dr}{t}. $$
Pulling out the factors of $t$ and rearranging gives the desired inequality,
$$ \left( \int_{[0, t]} f(r) dr \right)^2 \leq t \int_{[0, t]} f(r)^2 dr$$
where $f(r) = \nabla u (r \xi) \cdot \xi$.

Comment: haha, still don't see it. could you provide a little more detail? thanks!

Comment: @yoshi edited with more detail